# hadoop hive: calculate overlap in hive

Tags: hive

I have problem with hive that I have a list product that have 100 product. With struct of table:

```
CREATE TABLE `product` (productid STRING, product_name STRING)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

And a list information active of user but product with struct:

```
CREATE TABLE `information` (login_date STRING, productid STRING, account_name STRING)
PARTITIONED BY(dt STRING, app STRING)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

Now i want calculate overlap of every product with list product. But in hive i don't have any way to do them. Please give me any support. I realy realy need them. Thanks all.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by overlap?Have you looked at joins?

Comment: i have 100 products and example: i want calculate how many user use product A and use product B, A with C, A with D, ...after B with C, ....